# Leaked DB Connection

Tags: java, database, jdbc, jboss, database-connection

What is the best way to find that which part of my java code is opening a DB connection but not closing it?
I am stuck in a large batch process where it is hard to debug this issue.
I am using JBOSS application server.

Comment: A profiler that helps you on finding ever-growing things could also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/index.html) has two rules, that might help. I always found those useful:

> **ODR: Method may fail to close database resource (ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE)**
>
> The method creates a database resource (such as a database connection
>   or row set), does not assign it to any fields, pass it to other
>   methods, or return it, and does not appear to close the object on all
>   paths out of the method.  Failure to close database resources on all
>   paths out of a method may result in poor performance, and could cause
>   the application to have problems communicating with the database.
>
> **ODR: Method may fail to close database resource on exception (ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE_EXCEPTION_PATH)**
>
> The method creates a database resource (such as a database connection
>   or row set), does not assign it to any fields, pass it to other
>   methods, or return it, and does not appear to close the object on all
>   exception paths out of the method.  Failure to close database
>   resources on all paths out of a method may result in poor performance,
>   and could cause the application to have problems communicating with
>   the database.

Reference:

- http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE

Answer (score 2):

If you can't step through the code I would suggest the old fashioned way, add a bunch of System.outs and put details in the out statements that can help you figure out when the connection becomes opened.  You might be able to determine pretty closely to what part of your code is doing it.  At the very least, it may reduce the amount of code you need to focus on.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss data sources had forever a flag for this purpose

(from the DTD of data sources):

```
<!-- Whether to check for unclosed statements when a
     connection is returned to the pool and result sets are
     closed when a statement is closed/return to the prepared
     statement cache.
     valid values are:
     false - do not track statements and results
     true - track statements and result sets and warn when they are not closed
     nowarn - track statements but do no warn about them being unclosed (the default)
     e.g.
     <track-statements>nowarn</track-statements>
-->
```

So within your `*-ds.xml` file you set the element to `true` and watch the server log afterwards.